# Reset is not working when drop down with Chosen select Class

Tags: jquery

this is the code snippet for dropdown,

```
<tr>
    <td colspan=2>TID/CLLI A :
        <select data-placeholder= " " name="TidA" id="TidA" style="width:130px;" class ="chosen-select">            
            <%
                for (String clli :clliList){
            %>
            <option value="<%=clli%>"><%=clli%></option>
            <%
                }
            %>
        </select><br></br>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Below method is used for chosen select class,

```
$.fn.select2.amd.require(['select2/compat/matcher'], function (oldMatcher) {
    $(".chosen-select").select2({
        matcher: oldMatcher(matchStart)
    })
});
```

The values in dropdown is displayed from the servlet class using json. but when i click on the reset button type the selected value is not getting reset. It is displaying only the selected value. It should display the value in the dropdown with default selector as empty data . Please help me  to resolve this.

Comment: Create a sandbox demo that replicates the problem